# RecursiveLinkedCollections add methods

Tags: java

for one of my homework problems we are supposed to recursively add a node to a linked list. here is my code:

```
private LLNode<T> recAdd(LLNode<T> node, T data) {
    if(node.getLink() == null) {
        node.getLink().setLink(new LLNode<T>(data));
        }
    return recAdd(node.getLink(), data);
}

@Override
public boolean add(T data) {
    return recAdd(front, data);
}
```

As you can see, I am supposed to call the recAdd method from the add function, but there is an error on the

```
   return recAdd(front, data);
```

line, as I can not convert LLNode to boolean. Are there any suggestions? for the recAdd method, I am supposed to return a node, but I can not find a way to work around this. Also, here is a descirption of what the add method does in the CollectionInterface:

```
    /**
 * Attempts to add element to this collection.
 * @param element
 * @return Returns true if successful, false otherwise. 
 * Return false if element is null, otherwise true.
 */
boolean add(T data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always return `true` in the `add` operation, like

```java
@Override
public boolean add(T data) {
    recAdd(front, data);
    return true;
}
```

As you can see in the [`LinkedList` implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l337) and the [`ArrayList` implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l413), Java already does that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't clarify what the purpose of returning `boolean` in `add` is, so I believe this question can't be answered unless you give us more detail.

As per the convention of Java `Collection` interface, `Collection` and `List` should return `boolean` in add method. However, since your code doesn't handle `false` cases, why don't you return void or always `true` like native implementation in Java?

In case you still want to return `boolean` value, based or your code snippet, there are some work around like creating a field-flag indicating add status of `add`, or comparing the tail with the object you want to add. Note that these may not work depended on pre-condition (i.e: no duplicated values, etc).

Comment: /**
  * Attempts to add element to this collection.
  * param element
  * return Returns true if successful, false otherwise. 
  * Return false if element is null, otherwise true.
  */
    boolean add(T data);

Answer (score 0):

Must be

```
private LLNode<T> recAdd(LLNode<T> node, T data) {
    if(node.getLink() == null) {
        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(data);
        node.setLink(newNode);
        return newNode;
    }
    return recAdd(node.getLink(), data);
}

@Override
public boolean add(T data) {
    recAdd(front, data);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This seems to make the most sense, but when I run it i keep on getting a Null Pointer Exception... is there any reason why?

Comment: It does not handle starting state when collection is empty so it fails at `node.getLink()`